# Display latest 3 post in BigCommerce blog as slider

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I am new in BigCommerce, In my blog post I wanna display latest 3 blog post that is displaying as slideshow.

As of now in Slideshow, all the posts are come but I just wanna display latest 3 blog posts there.

Some one,please help me out.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PHP in Bigcommerce as it is a SaaS platform. You can write a simple javascript that would make this possible. I would suggest looking into a jQuery plugin as it will most likely make this much simpler.